# c# datagridview randomly lose the columns properties

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working on an application that contains a lot of datagridviews.
Randomly, after I've worked on a form in designer mode, when i build the project, one of the datagridviews becomes crazy.
The columns order change, the visible / invisible properties are lost, even the column names are sometimes reset to default.
The problem isn't specific to one datagridview, I've experienced this on many of them, randomly.
It's not specific to one form neither, I've seen this in several forms.

The autoGenerateColumns properties is set to false for all of the datagridviews.
I have renamed all the columns using unique names because i read that it could be a problem related to names allready used elsewhere> it's still happening.

It's like if the designer.cs sometimes becomes crazy and reset one of the datagridview.This is pretty annoying, each time i make a new build of the application, i can end with a broken datagridview even if i didn't touch it.

Is there a known issue with datagridviews that could explain this ?
I'm on .NET Framework 3.5
Can a newer Framework version solve this ?

I didn't post any code because it's not really related to any code...

Thanks in advance for any idea / information

PS : sorry for my english

Comment: VS version? I recall there was a problem with winforms designer in past (really long time ago, ~10 years), where if you have form opened, then running (which includes building) application may corrupt the form (something is moved, loses properties, etc.). Try to install newest VS or close form designers before build.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Pro.
Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Suggest you create another solution, move these form into new solution.

Comment: I think i have a clue.
The problem just happened again.
One of the column totally disapeared from the datagridview.
It was a column of type "CalendarColumn"
This is a custom column type found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx
Could all this be caused by this CalendarColumn ?